# Visualize correlation between two columns in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, machine-learning, statistics

I have two columns. The first column contains data related to salary and second column contains data related to house_rent of employees. Now using python I want to find the correlation between the two. Is there some way in Python to visualize the correlation:

```
Salary   house_rent
10000    50
10000    50
3000     465
```

The focus of this task is to find how correlated salary and house rent of employees are. E.g. some employees may have huge salary but small house rent and some others may have small salary and huge house rent. Note that it can very well be the case that two people have the same salary and house rent. Is it possible to visualize this in python?

Answer (score 3):

You can plot a linear regression line using sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression :

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html

You can also build a correlation matrix use pyplot.matshow() from matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.matshow(dataframe.corr())
plt.show()
```

Comment: What is dataframe here?

Comment: dataframe would be an instance of your above dataset. Just store your dataset as a csv file (eg using excel) and import it using pandas library.                              import pandas as pd                                                                                                     dataframe = pd.read_csv('file_name')

Answer (score 2):

As has already been told, you can use `corr` method present in `pandas` to get the correlation.
A better way to visualize would be to use `seaborn` library instead of `matplotlib`.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)    
df= pd.read_csv('path_to_your_csv_file')
g = sns.pairplot(df)
plt.show()
```

For further details refer https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html
and 
https://towardsdatascience.com/visualizing-data-with-pair-plots-in-python-f228cf529166

Comment: You need to call `plt.show()`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: It shows 4 plots what do the individual plots means

Comment: It is pairing up all the columns with each other. Refer the link given in answer or better yet search for pairplot interpretation on the internet.